# Insert inputtextfield to <body> in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i am new to React JS.
I am trying to use input inside the Body tags of My application. I have managed to have the header and footer. Now i want to have something inside the  tags in ReactJS

I think i am missing something, But my code is looking something like this :

Css

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
  }

.header{
    background-color: #007FC0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.container{
    flex : 1 1 auto;
    color:white;
}


.footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #16192C;
}
```

Now The Code which utilises the Css looks like this

**React**

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css'

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        </header>
        <body>

        </body>
        <footer className="footer">
        </footer>

    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

How do I put things like Inputboxes? checkboxes etc.

I just need clarification.

**Edit**

My code Looks like this now, Its still not showing. Code Looks like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css'

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        </header>
            <form>
                <label>
                    Hello React Label
                </label>
            </form>
        <footer className="footer">
        </footer>

    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

The output is still empty and looks like this

[image: 9992.png]

Still very empty.

Comment: @AjeetShah Pls see Edits

Comment: @AjeetShah, Please see Edits and i am not using bootsrap. Just some simple Css.

Comment: It is CSS issue. Remove `position: fixed;` from "header" class. I am not good at CSS, I can't explain "why".

Comment: ok, it removed it. Thanks. Its fine

Comment: I hope you can now see the "label"? You can debug such issues using "browser developer tool" by inspecting the HTML.